# Optimizer Lock Hint Option Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm a newbie hope you guys could help me with it. I'm working on a query right now seems that I'm stuck with this error Optimizer Lock Hint Option.  I haven't encountered this error before.

I followed this tutorial from a website about [SQL Pivot](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/converting-rows-to-columns-pivot-and-columns-to-rows-unpivot-in-sql-server.html). Everything works perfectly except on when I run it with EXEC sp_executesql. I tried everything I can to fix this issue but no luck.  Its my first time to use Pivot in SQL server.

Please check my code below:

What I'm achieving for is that I'm trying to converting about 50 rows into columns for my stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @CustFeedCols AS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @CustFeedQuery AS NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @CustFeedCols = COALESCE(@CustFeedCols + ',','') + QUOTENAME(custfeed)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1000 replace(replace(replace(replace(custfeed ,' ',''),'.',''),'-',''),'–','') as custfeed FROM efp_touchCRM.dbo.efp_customertouch 
WHERE custfeed <> '' AND custfeed is NOT null AND custfeed <> 'Sold Sample'
ORDER BY custfeed) AS custfeed

SELECT @CustFeedCols

SET @CustFeedQuery = N'SELECT ' + @CustFeedCols + ' FROM efp_touchCRM.dbo.efp_customertouch PIVOT(GROUPING(custfeed)) FOR custfeed IN (' + @CustFeedCols + ')) AS P'

SELECT @CustFeedQuery

EXEC sp_executesql @CustFeedQuery --This is where the error appears.
                                  --Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Thanks for the reply everyone! See the edited code with the error provided on the 2nd line.  Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get an error message? What is not right here? What does the contents of @CustFeedQuery look like?

Comment: Hi Sean Lange! Yep I got an error, see the error below the EXEC in the code, the 2nd line.  Thanks,

Comment: What does the contents of @CustFeedQuery look like? You should select or print your variable instead of executing it so you can see the code that is going to execute. That is where the error is.

Comment: Hi Sean Lange! here is the print result for the @CustFeedQuery: `SELECT [ColdCallFirstCommunication],[ContactInformation],[CSMorecommunicationNeeded] FROM efp_touchCRM.dbo.efp_customertouch PIVOT(custfeed) FOR custfeed IN ([ColdCallFirstCommunication],[ContactInformation],[CSMorecommunicationNeeded])) AS P`

Comment: Your pivot is not written correctly, the syntax is wrong, and you don't have a valid aggregate function in it.  You've written it like a table hint, but its not -- you need to do what Sean says, print it, and see how it looks, and tweak the dynamic sql as needed.  Lookup the proper way to write a pivot.

Comment: Hi There Sean Lange! Sorry I took so long.  I found out that I lack aggregate, many thanks to you as well as Jiggs.  Right now I'm facing another problem which is incorrect syntax near ')' and I don't know why, I double check the syntax on the site, it seems correct but  when I ran the query I got the syntax near error. please see the code again. I already edited the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on examples:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

> ```
> -- Pivot table with one row and five columns
> SELECT 'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days, 
> [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
> FROM
> (SELECT DaysToManufacture, StandardCost 
>     FROM Production.Product) AS SourceTable
> PIVOT
> (
> AVG(StandardCost)
> FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
> ) AS PivotTable;
> ```

In your code:

1. no aggregation function
2. troubles with parenthesis

:

```
PIVOT
(
  custfeed <<<
) <<<
FOR custfeed IN (
...)) as P
```

Comment: Hi There Ivan Starostin! Thank you for the reply, I already followed the syntax right now but I have another problem occurred.  It seems that before the PIVOT syntax, I got an error syntax error near '(' and I don't know why, I already followed the code as what is mentioned above.  Would you help me with it?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sorry, I think its my bad.  I'm using SQL server 2008 not 2008 R2 and also I couldn't upgrade the database compatibility to 90 because I have only 70/80 compatibility option available. The database is too old and  I think it is the reason why the syntax isn't applicable.  Well I will just leave it there. Right now I will open a new question and find another way to fix this issue.  Thanks anyway!  Best regards,